# Scraping escaped JSON data within a <script type="text/javascript"> in R

Tags: html, r, json, web-scraping

I am currently trying to scrape the data from the two graphs on following html page (information from two graphs listed there: Forsmark and Ringhals): https://group.vattenfall.com/se/var-verksamhet/vara-energislag/karnkraft/aktuell-karnkraftsproduktion

The data originate from script tags like this (fragment)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/ productionData = JSON.parse("{\"timestamp\":1582642616000,\"powerPlant\":\"Ringhals\", // etc
</script>
```

I would like to get two dataframes that looks like these:

```
F1          F2          F3       
number      number      number
```

and

```
R1          R2          R3       
number      number      number
```

I tried to use XML and xpath to parse an html page but did not get anywhere with that.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you scraping? The (underlying data for the) graphs for Forsmark and Ringhals?

Comment: Yes, they are stored under <script type="text/javascript"> in HTML.

Comment: Those charts are `<iframe>`s that load from https://gvp.vattenfall.com/sweden/produced-power/iframe/forsmark and https://gvp.vattenfall.com/sweden/produced-power/iframe/ringhals I see now. Since there are tonnes of script tags on that page, it would have been helpful to add a landmark, like "The script tag that contains `productionData` JSON."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those charts are `<iframe>`s that load from

- https://gvp.vattenfall.com/sweden/produced-power/iframe/forsmark and
- https://gvp.vattenfall.com/sweden/produced-power/iframe/ringhals

so you should scrape those two pages directly.

This was an interesting challenge.

It becomes not too hard with [`rvest`](https://rvest.tidyverse.org/) and [`jsonlite`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jsonlite/versions/1.6.1), which you will have to install if you don't already have. Both require [`rtools`](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).

Try this:

```
library('rvest')
library('jsonlite')

# Load the URL (do the same for the other iframe)
url <- 'https://gvp.vattenfall.com/sweden/produced-power/iframe/forsmark'

# Parse it
webpage <- read_html(url)

# Extract the script element. That's a CSS selector for the specific one that holds the json data
# You can find it in your browser's DevTools by finding the script element
# and right-clicking, choosing Copy > CSS Path/Selector
script_element <- html_nodes(webpage, 'body > section:nth-child(2) > script:nth-child(2)')

# Extract its string content
json = html_text(script_element)

# Clean it up
json = gsub("\n        /*<![CDATA[*/\n        productionData = JSON.parse(", "", json, fixed=TRUE)
json = gsub(");\n        /*]]>*/\n    ", "", json, fixed=TRUE)
json = gsub("\"{", "{\"", json, fixed=TRUE)
json = gsub("}\"", "}", json, fixed=TRUE)
json = gsub("{\"\\\"", "{\\\"", json, fixed=TRUE)

# Extract data
data = jsonlite::fromJSON(gsub("\\\"", "\"", json, fixed=TRUE))
```

Caveat: I'm not really an R expert, there is likely a more elegant way of doing this (particularly the data cleaning portion). But it works.

For historical preservation, that takes this DOM node (the text content of the `<script>` tag):

```
"\n        /*<![CDATA[*/\n        productionData = JSON.parse(\"{\\\"timestamp\\\":1582643336000,\\\"powerPlant\\\":\\\"Forsmark\\\",\\\"blockProductionDataList\\\":[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"F1\\\",\\\"production\\\":998.86194,\\\"percent\\\":99.88619},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"F2\\\",\\\"production\\\":1120.434,\\\"percent\\\":97.8545},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"F3\\\",\\\"production\\\":1189.7126,\\\"percent\\\":99.55754}]}\");\n        /*]]>*/\n    "
```

and will result in data of this format

```
> data
$timestamp
[1] 1.582647e+12

$powerPlant
[1] "Forsmark"

$blockProductionDataList
  name production  percent
1   F1   997.7902 99.77902
2   F2  1131.6150 98.83100
3   F3  1190.0520 99.58594
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for detailed answer and explanation! It works perfectly.

Comment: @Kat Awesome and my pleasure! It was fun to work through, this was a very unusual case (for me) with the JSON actually escaped within the page in a script tag.